# How to make multiple third party GCM servers with same api key

Tags: android, android-notifications

I need a way to make any number of third party GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) servers using single Google API key, so that for different set of client, I just need to make new server url, using same API key.

This way i can get client specific push notifications in Android without making new Google account.

First of all, is this possible?

Thanx in advance